# Sorting of array level wise in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I have an array of strings in which individual element is separated by pipe(|). 
Sample data is :
   A|1447|1
   B|150|2
   C|0|3
   D|66|3
   E|0|4
   F|350|2

First Column is the name of function. 
Second column is the time taken to execute
Third column is  the level at which the function occurs with respect to main.

I have to arrange it in a form which is sorted on the basis of middle element in descending order such that the output of above sample is:

A|1447|1

F|350|2
B|150|2
D|66|3
E|0|4

C|0|3

The above pattern suggests that Function A took 1447 ms . Out of this 1447 ms 350 ms were spent in function F and 150 ms in function B  . Remaining was spent in functions not mentioned here. 
In the similar manner , out of 150 ms spent in function B ,66 were spent in function D and 0 ms in function C. Out of 66 ms in function D 0 were spent in function E . Meaning it was spent in some other function not mentioned .

Considering we are evaluating the data given to us. We have to sort them and take a new array out of them in perl.

Comment: So sorting with a custom sort comparison. What have you tried?

Comment: @ikegami no, it's a tree building problem. e.g. E (level 4) has to stay with the closest previous level 3 (D). sorting only occurs within each set of children

Comment: @ysth, ok... I don't see that mentioned anywhere, and the example doesn't demonstrate (or contradict) that. But if that's the case, build a tree, and sort the each array of children.

Comment: I am newbie to perl and do not know how to build a tree out of this data

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the children of each node of a tree, you will first need to build a tree!

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( current_sub say );

my $tree = do {
   my @ancestors = [ undef, undef, undef, [] ];
   while (<>) {
      chomp;
      my ($name, $time, $depth) = split /\|/;

      die "Bad data\n" if $depth < 1;
      die "Bad data\n" if $depth > @ancestors;
      splice(@ancestors, $depth);

      my $node = [ $name, $time, $depth, [] ];
      push @{ $ancestors[-1][3] }, $node;
      push @stack, $node;
   }

   my @roots = @{ $ancestors[0][3] };
   die "No roots\n"       if !@roots;
   die "Multiple roots\n" if @roots > 1;
   $roots[0]
};

sub {
   my ($node) = @_;
   say join "|", @$node[0,1,2];
   __SUB__->($_) for sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] } @{ $node->[3] };
}->($tree);
```

Comment: Unable to understand the syntax

Comment: What syntax do you not understand?